# creating and managing serverless application using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS SAM for creating and managing Lambda function application with staging approvals with the pipeline in AWS{code build and Codepipeline} .Here are the questions that  I have:

1 How can I set up the approval stages in different account like Dev ,staging and Deployment with manual approval?

2 Do I have to set up the pipeline in each account or just in the deployment account? and how will this set up look like?

Can you please advise on how to achieve this goal.